# You can’t read me, yet here we are

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> You can’t read me, yet here we are.
> As good as line 5, but just as far.
> Doctors may share this trait.
> Or maybe just a half-eaten cake.

**What am I?**

---

The answer is a single English word.
This is my first riddle, so feedback is appreciated!

---

**Hint 1:**

> See what the lines are saying about the word carefully.

**Hint 2:**

> One of the lines here has the definition to the answer.

**Hint 3:**

> When looking back at your writing from many, many years ago

**Hint 3 (Larger hint):**

> Foreign texts may seem like this to you.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: @Stevo Hello! So, I made this question myself, but if you don’t trust me I can take it down if you want.

Comment: @Buzzyy No need, all fine - Stevo was just checking, as any puzzles from elsewhere need to be attributed to their original creator, so credit can be paid where due. If you created it yourself, that's fine just to say so :) Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: Is it rot13(Oynax)?

Comment: @ielyamani If I used rot13 correctly, no, but it's close!

Comment: Rot13(V guvax vg unf gb qb jvgu juvgr. Lbh pna’g ernq n oynax yvar (be juvgr vax ba n juvgr cncre).. Qbpgbef jrne juvgr, naq gur vpvat ba n pnxr vf juvgr.)

Comment: @ielyamani VERY close! It not that though.

Comment: I feel like the more hints there are, the more confused I get...

Comment: @Auribouros I see why it could feel like that: since the hints may be more confusing. I’ll probably edit the second hint to make it clearer.

Comment: The only thing I can glean from hint 3 on first glance is "Oh no it's all written in French!"

Comment: @Auribouros That reminds me of another ‘hint’; I’ll add it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> 

sorry...

> illegible (edited, first try was unreadable)

You can’t read me, yet here we are.

> or as hint 2: One of the lines here has the definition to the answer.

As good as line 5, but just as far.

> as others stated line 5 doesn't exist, therefore can't be read

Doctors may share this trait.

> Doctors are often said to have a bad handwriting

Or maybe just a half-eaten cake.

> the text on the cake would be half-eaten, too

When looking back at your writing from many, many years ago

> sometimes we change our way to write over the years.

Comment: Rot13 FB PYBFR! Gur nafjre vf nyzbfg na rknpg flabalz sbe guvf: gel punatvat lbhe nafjre!

Comment: Well done! You got it!

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit whacky, here goes:

The answer is

> time.

My reasoning:

You can’t read me, yet here we are.

> We can't read time, we can only read clocks that conceptualise time for us. I thought "yet here we are" could be a reference to space-time: **when** we and **where** we are is connected. Alternatively, I read the saying as "we are" and "yet", which are references to present or future tense.

As good as line 5, but just as far.

> Line five doesn't exist (yet), but may well do in a future time(line).

Doctors may share this trait.

> I thought of Doctor Who. The Doctor is a time lord or time lady. This is their race, so they share 'time' as part of their identity. The Doctor is of course only one person, but the different incarnations are usually referred to as "the doctors".

Or maybe just a half-eaten cake.

> It's a mnemonic device for children to learn the analogue clock as pieces of cake. A half-eaten cake could indicate half-an-hour of time.

Fwiw, I think this is not the intended answer because I couldn't find a way to explain that

> the first line can do it all on its own. I also considered 'genome' as an answer but the half-eaten cake didn't work.

Comment: Wow! This is actually a really good answer, and I was quite surprised at how all the hints lined up. This isn’t the answer though. Nice try!

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure about this one, but... maybe it is

> space

You can’t read me, yet here we are.

> Lots of spaces there, but they cannot be "read"

As good as line 5, but just as far.

> There is no line 5, but instead just blank space

Doctors may share this trait.

> Doctors could share office space and working space (but that isn't really a trait).

Or maybe just a half-eaten cake.

> The eaten half is now just space.

Comment: Good answer, but sadly not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I *will* try my hand at another answer, is the answer

> Gibberish

*You can't read me, yet here we are.*

> You can't read gibberish, because, it doesn't mean anything, it's gibberish

*As good as line 5, but just as far.*

> Line 5 doesn't exist, it means as much as gibberish does, which is not much

*Doctors may share this trait.*

> Doctors are known to write in a confusing way, a borderline unreadable mess that's somehow understood by pharmacists

*Or maybe just a half-eaten cake.*

> This maybe refers to talking with your mouth full, or the leftovers of the cake looking unappealing, and haphazardly placed

---

I think the answer is

> **Nothing**

*You can't read me, yet here we are.*

> You can't read "nothing", but you can read the word itself, and sometimes adding spaces (nothing*s*) between words helps

*As good as line 5, but just as far.*

> Line 5 doesn't exist, nothing to see there

*Doctors may share this trait.*

> Doctors are allowed to share nothing about their patients, as per the [Hippocratic Oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocratic_Oath)

*Or maybe just a half-eaten cake.*

> There's no more of half of this cake, it's gone, nothing's left!

Comment: This answer is also reasonably close; but is not correct, sadly. Good try though!

Comment: @Buzzyy I assume my second answer isn't correct either? :)

Comment: No, someone else got the answer first, but good try!